# Does Android/Chrome fully support background-clip CSS property? Works fine in FF/Chrome on PC and Mac

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, background, clip

I have a bit of text that I am applying a background-image to appear as the fill using the 'background-clip' property. This effect works in Firefox and Chrome on Mac and PC but on an android device using chrome, only thing I have to test on, the text is 'there' meaning I can touch the screen and it highlights but the effect is not there making it appear 'invisible'. The text is Z-indexed over a canvas and again looks fine in a desktop browser. Any ideas on why android/chrome is not rendering it the same?

P.S. I can't get just this section split out in a pen so see attached code:

HTML

```
<div id="light-intro-wrapper">
<div id="light-intro">THIS IS<br>
  TEXT <br>
  <a class="down_block go" href="#content_a"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a> </div>
<div id="3d-graph">
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div>
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="scene-nav-info" style="display: none;">Left-click: rotate, Mouse-wheel/middle-click: zoom, Right-click: pan</div>
        <div class="scene-tooltip">&nbsp;</div>
        <canvas height="958" style="width: 1920px; height: 958px;" width="1920"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="graph-info-msg">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content_a">&nbsp;</div>
```

CSS

```
canvas#canvas {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#light-intro {
    height: 200px;
    background: url("image.jpg");
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;  
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 7vh;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 400px;
    top: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    right: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}


.down_block {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    height: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 55px;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #FFF url("http://chrismccormick.com/wp-content/uploads/cellular.jpg");
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.go {
    color: transparent;
}
```

EDIT: Cleaned up markup/CSS

Namaste
-mk

Comment: I'm gonna go with 'No' to the original question and mark it as answered if no one wants to chime in to a definitive answer or provide a solution.
The code is in order as far as I can tell, and works well cross platform minus the 'background-clip' property.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not supported.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27069647)

Comment: ...I am the author, and I have been both critical and clear. That is the answer.

Comment: I'm hitting the same roadblock! I guess we should stay away from poorly implemented properties like this. I'm off to find a different way to get the effect.